# Difference between custom getter and equal(=) assigning

Tags: android, kotlin

**Update:**

I'm sorry, I should have added more codes to my original question.

Here is the code accessing `attributionUrl`.

```
class GalleryViewHolder(
    private val binding: ListItemPhotoBinding
) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
    init {
        binding.setClickListener { view ->
            binding.photo?.let { photo ->
                val uri = Uri.parse(photo.user.attributionUrl) // Here!
                val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri)
                view.context.startActivity(intent)
            }
        }
    }

    fun bind(item: UnsplashPhoto) {
        binding.apply {
            photo = item
            executePendingBindings()
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the error trace.

```
2022-02-25 15:18:10.792 1178-1178/com.google.samples.apps.sunflower E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.google.samples.apps.sunflower, PID: 1178
    java.lang.NullPointerException: uriString
        at android.net.Uri$StringUri.<init>(Uri.java:507)
        at android.net.Uri$StringUri.<init>(Uri.java:497)
        at android.net.Uri.parse(Uri.java:469)
        at com.google.samples.apps.sunflower.adapters.GalleryAdapter$GalleryViewHolder$1.onClick(GalleryAdapter.kt:60)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7455)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7432)
        at android.view.View.access$3700(View.java:835)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28810)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7842)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
```

Thank you so much!

---

**Original Message:**

I’m studying Google’s android sunflower sample.

I can observe several usages of custom getter which is not familiar to me in view model and data class.

But I’m not sure when to use custom getter and equal(=) assigning.

Especially, when I change below

```
data class UnsplashUser(
    @field:SerializedName("name") val name: String,
    @field:SerializedName("username") val username: String
) {
    val attributionUrl: String
        get() {
            return "https://unsplash.com/$username?utm_source=sunflower&utm_medium=referral"
        }
}
```

to

```
data class UnsplashUser(
    @field:SerializedName("name") val name: String,
    @field:SerializedName("username") val username: String
) {
    val attributionUrl = "https://unsplash.com/$username?utm_source=sunflower&utm_medium=referral"
}
```

and try to access to `attributionURL` property, Null Pointer Exception occurs.

Can anyone explain me about the difference between custom getter and equal(=) assigning?

Thanks.

Comment: Add the exception with question and code also how are you accessing this field

Comment: Kindly add error logs

Answer (score 1):

The difference is the `get()` function creates a new string and returns it *every time* you access `attributionUrl`. The straight assignment creates the string *once*, when the object is created.

A typical reason for doing this is if the value always needs to be calculated, e.g. something is changing - like if your `username` value could change, you'd want `attributionUrl` to include that updated value. If you just assigned a string at construction, it would be fixed and wouldn't reflect any changes to `username`

Another reason for a getter is if you rely on stuff that isn't ready at construction. If `username` had to be set on the object, later (instead of passed in as a constructor parameter) then setting `attributionUrl` during construction wouldn't work - you wouldn't have the data you need yet. Another option for that is a `lazy` delegate:

```
val attributionUrl: String by lazy { "hi $username etc" }
```

That assigns the value *once* like a normal assignment, but only does it the first time `attributionUrl` is read. So if you can guarantee you have `username` by then, it works out.

---

That's not why you're getting a `NullPointerException` - the only variable you're accessing in `attributionUrl`'s getter is `username`, and it doesn't matter if that's null in a string - it'll just say `null`

You should post the stacktrace like people are asking for, at a guess it's because you changed `attributionUrl` to a property *with a backing field* (i.e. a stored value in memory) instead of a getter function that just creates a new value each time.

That will be serialised/deserialised in the JSON by default - and if you have stored data that **doesn't** have a value for `attributionUrl` (which should be the case, you weren't storing it when you had the getter) then when the deserialiser tries to create an `UnsplashUser` object, it doesn't have a value for `attributionUrl`, which isn't allowed to be null either.

You could try making the field transient:

```
@Transient
val attributionUrl = "https://unsplash.com/$username?utm_source=sunflower&utm_medium=referral"
```

which excludes it from serialisation. Which is what you want, since it's a derived value - it doesn't need to be stored!